# How to create new columns by extracting numbers from a vector column with regex?

Tags: r, data.table

I need to extract numbers from a vector column using regex and create columns for each number. The length of the vector will not be the same for each row.

For other purposes such as counting the number of elements within the vector I have used

```
str_count(DATA$vectorCOL, '[0-9.+]+')
```

This is the data column

```
vectorCOL
63.
11., 36., 45+1., 79., 90+1.

45., 80., 87.
```

Expected output

```
vectorCOL                    col1  col2 col3  col4 col5
63.                          63    NA   NA    NA   NA
11., 36., 45+1., 79., 90+1.  11    36   45+1  79   90+1
                             NA    NA   NA    NA   NA
45., 80., 87.                45    80   87    NA   NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `cSplit`

```
splitstackshape::cSplit(df, "vectorCOL", sep = ",", drop = FALSE)
#                vectorCOL vectorCOL_1 vectorCOL_2 vectorCOL_3 vectorCOL_4 vectorCOL_5
#1:                     63.          63          NA        <NA>          NA        <NA>
#2: 11.,36.,45+1.,79.,90+1.          11          36       45+1.          79       90+1.
#3:                                  NA          NA        <NA>          NA        <NA>
#4:             45.,80.,87.          45          80         87.          NA        <NA>
```

If we don't want "." in the output, we can remove them first using `gsub`.

```
df$vectorCOL <- gsub("\\.", "",df$vectorCOL)
```

**data**

```
df <-  structure(list(vectorCOL = c("63.", "11., 36., 45+1., 79., 90+1.", 
"", "45., 80., 87.")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: data.table has `tstrsplit`, so something like `setDT(df)[, paste0("col", 1:5) := tstrsplit(vectorCOL, "., ", fixed = TRUE)]` should be more diomatic

Comment: @DavidArenburg yeah..but the tricky part is we don't know beforehand if it is going to be `paste0("col", 1:5)` or `paste0("col", 1:4)`. Maybe need to count `,` first.

Comment: OP said, they figured that out already. Usually you just need to combine `max` with `stri_count` or such in order to find it once, and then you just use it in `paste`

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`:

```
df <- df[, c(vectorCOL = list(vectorCOL), tstrsplit(vectorCOL, ","))]
setnames(df, names(df), sub("V", "col", names(df)))
df
#                      vectorCOL col2 col3   col4 col5   col6
# 1:                         63.  63. <NA>   <NA> <NA>   <NA>
# 2: 11., 36., 45+1., 79., 90+1.  11.  36.  45+1.  79.  90+1.
# 3:                             <NA> <NA>   <NA> <NA>   <NA>
# 4:               45., 80., 87.  45.  80.    87. <NA>   <NA>
```